# WPF - Wrong focus when multiple windows are shown

Tags: wpf, focus, childwindow

we are experiencing a strange behavior regarding focus between multiple windows.

Our scenario looks like this:

"Window A" opens child "Window B" using the Show method (without precifying the owner of the window).  Both Windows are totally independent.

In "Window B" a click on a button opens "Window C" (which displays a modal window).

A --> B --> C

When "Window C" is closed, the focus is given back to "window A".

In my mind, "Window B" should get the focus back as it's the "logical" owner of the window (because I did not specify the Owner).

It looks like the focus is given back to the first instanciated window.

Is there a way to "force" the focus, in my case, on "Window B".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
B.Activate();
```

right after your ShowDialog() returns.

Comment: Thanks.  After further investigation, it looks like a bug in our framework.  The Activate method is properly called, but for some reason "Window C" is closed using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. The Activate method returns "false" because "Window C" is not closed at that time.  If I change the "BeginInvoke" to "Invoke", it works fine. Our development team will investigate the issue.